# query for development of a rota application

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

how can we prepare a rota application which changes the shift so that all the employees get  to work in different shifts and in the month end the number of shifts done by all the employees should be the same..

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is too broad a question. You're meant to ask more specific things here. For example, you could ask what design pattern fits your problem, or if there is an open source rota app out there

Comment: I mean to ask which algorithm can we use to do this?

Comment: I thought of using the time difference as one of parameter to do so. To be very specific the time difference in the end of the shift today and the start of the shift the next very day.  Hope this shortens my question..

Comment: We need to know more about the way your data is structured (i.e. tables, just the ones related to this problem). Please edit your question adding that information

Comment: I am planning to have almost  to have a table just for the parameters and the rest other tables will have the details related to the employees.

Comment: table related to employee details, 1 table related to details of the shift and then 1 more table related to the details about the holidays.

Comment: I can change the design of the tables once the I have a algorithm which can help me generate the rota for the employees. So that the shift doesn't repeat for the employees and at the end of the month the shift done by all the employees remains the same.

Comment: Hope this helps??? Any helps regarding the application is most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if I understood correctly, the problem you want to solve is the following:

**Input:**: You define `S` different Shifts for a Month `M`, and you have `E` employees.

**Output:**: Given the input, you have to define a schedule for each employee, that is, assign Shifts from `S` to them along the month `M`. When doing so, you must meet two objectives:

- All Employees get to work in different Shifts
- The total amount of Shifts assigned to each Employee must be the same

To achieve this, there are lots of possible algorithms. Off the top of my head, here's one in C-style pseudocode (you write in VB.NET):

```
CircularArray shifts = GetDefinedShifts();
foreach(day in Month){
    foreach( employee in Employees ){
       employee.Schedule.AssignShift( Month, day, shifts.Current() );
       shifts.Next();
    }
}
```

A `CircularArray` goes back to the first element when you call `Next` standing on the last one. However, this algorithm fails if `#E == #S`: every employee gets always the same shift. So it's not that easy. But this naive algorithm can get you started thinking a better one. If I come up with something better, I'll post it.

On the other hand, why reinvent the wheel? There are open source solutions available, such as [this one](http://www.splinterware.com/products/autorota.htm). And there's a list of similar software [here](http://www.shambles.net/pages/staff/ttsoft/).

Comment: That seems to be the one I was trying to find I will try this and let you know ASAP how this worked for me. Thanks a lot for your help and time in this regard, I really appreciate your help in making me such an application. I will try to check the links provided by and see how that helps me to solve my issue. Once again thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: But can anyone help me do the same thing with SQL server

Comment: So that I can understand the logic which might help me create it in a better way..

Comment: You should ask that in a separate question. In the meantime, google `Entity Framework`